# How can I call a excel file generated with Sample_<Timestamp>.doc everytime in windows batch file?

Tags: excel, windows, batch-file, jmeter, wildcard

I am creating a batch file which calls the excel file to generate the graphical report. Every-time excel generated with the new timestamp. So, my excel file caption is like: Sample_Timestamp. Here Sample will remain same every-time but only change is timestamp.

**Note: This excel overwrites the old/previous excels.**

My problem is that I am not able to call that excel. Thanks in advance!

Adding more details:

**Scenario:**

I have a large set of automation test suite of JMeter. And I run this suite at every sprint which generates the result in excel(csv) file like: suitename_timestamp.csv.

[image]

After this, JMeter reads this .csv file and generates the graphical report by using following command line:

[image]

I am doing this by command line but problem comes when my file name(timestamp) changes at every run and I want to pick the latest one generated:

Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: Well, it would have been usefull if you showed actual samples of everything, now this will end up as another closed question.

Comment: More details had been added. Please refer that.

Comment: ok, that is a little better.

Answer (score 2):

As per your screenshots you attempted to edit into my answer, you did it wrong:
something like this.. ensure to change `???` to username you've hidden

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\users\???\Desktop\APIAutomation\Results\Excel"
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /od "LMS*.csv"') do (
    set "_cmd=%%i"
)
call "C:\some dir\jmeter\jmeter.bat" -g "%_cmd%" -o "C:/users/???/Desktop/????/Results/HTML"
```

Comment: sorry for asking a silly question as i am new to this and have no idea: where to place the call command as shown in image or just use as it is by just providing the path to csv.

Comment: Thanks Gerhard! I will try this and let you know.

Comment: I'd use the quoted syntax `set "_cmd=%%i"`, and I'd also quote the path part in `start "" "%_cmd%"`...

Comment: @Prateek.. I rejected the edit, but I have seen the screenshots and added a correction in my answer to that. Please edit your question and add the screenshots if needed

Comment: I tried the same as you suggested. Everything runs fine expect report generation. -o "C:\users\???\Desktop\????\Results\HTML"----This command generates the report but not generating in my case nor giving any error. Using this:                                                                 @echo off
cd /d "c:\users\??\Desktop\APIAutomation\Results\Excel"
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /od "LMS*.csv"') do (
    set "_cmd=%%i"
)
call jmeter -g "%_cmd%" -o "C:\Users\??\Desktop\APIAutomation\Results\HTML"

Comment: ok, so however you manually ran the command, you need to do it in the call here. `call jmeter -g "%_cmd%" -o "C:\users\youruser\Desktop\youruser\Results\HTML"` else edit your question with a screenshot of what happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188670/discussion-between-gerhard-barnard-and-prateek).